# How to delete a very strange file from desktop

Tags: windows-7

On my desktop WIN7 I have a ZERO length file with non-ascii character name and 12 characters after the dot. I cannon delete the file, rename it, move it to another folder, or remove it from the desktop. If I try, it says "This file is no longer located in c:\Users\Dell\Desktop Verify the item location and try again" CMD shows the file on the desktop with ZERO length
I downloaded and tried eraser, unlocked, or everything even remotely possible to help Nothing worked I am trying to delete this strange file. Any help would be appreciated
Thank you
Dave

Comment: What is the file?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/31587/how-to-force-windows-xp-to-rename-a-file-with-a-special-character, http://superuser.com/questions/165395/how-to-delete-invalid-files-with-colon-in-their-name-under-windows, http://superuser.com/questions/510529/how-can-i-delete-a-folder-with-illegal-characters

Answer (score 0):

You might have illegal characters in file name,start a cmd instance with admin rights and run

```
chkdsk /V /f
```

Might ask you for reboot.