# Folder is not deleting. How to delete this folder?

Tags: windows, unicode

[image: Screenshot]

I am trying to delete "Games" folder. Folder size is huge. But it's not deleting. Even not showing a message.

If I try to delete using cmd. But it shows another error.

[image: Command Line]

What should I do now?

Comment: Can you try this?: `rmdir /s "\\?\D:\Games"`

Comment: run chkdsk, this looks like a corrupted file-system.

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar Same problem as 2nd image.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few things that you can try:

- run chkdsk on your D: drive and then reboot your computer and try again.  I'm running linux, so I can't verify, but as I recall the command should be `chkdsk D: /f`
- If that doesn't work, try downloading [Eraser](http://eraser.heidi.ie/) and using eraser to delete the folder.  It deletes the folders/files where they can't be recovered, but I've had cases where it will delete files that Windows isn't able to using normal means.
- If that doesn't work, you may have to download a [linux live CD](http://www.slitaz.org/en/get/#stable) and [burn it](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd451080.aspx) to a disk/[boot off of it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD).

I haven't personally run into this issue before, but hopefully one of these things will help you clear these files off of your drive.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. It worked. But, that folder size was more thank 30gb. After deleting that my drive doesn't free those spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Per the answers in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/510529/how-can-i-delete-a-folder-with-illegal-characters), the Windows API simply cannot handle certain odd characters.  The accepted answer offers that you can try `chkdsk`.  The other option is to boot to a Linux LiveCD that can handle the names, access the hard drive from the LiveCD, and rename them.

Edit: Misread your screenshot.  Removed my reference to your C:\ drive.